# how to resolve this error in ethereum

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

**code:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

contract SendMoney{

    uint public balanceRecieved;
    function recieveMoney() public payable {
        balanceRecieved += msg.value;  // msg.value stores the amount of ether recieved when function is called
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function withdrawMoney() public {
        address payable toAdress = msg.sender;
         
        toAdress.transfer(this.getBalance());
    }
}
```

**error i get:**

Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable.

Comment: What is the line/function concerned ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
payable(msg.sender).transfer(this.getBalance());
```

Instead of:

```
address payable toAdress = msg.sender ;
         
toAdress.transfer(this.getBalance());
```